# XNode to string for a child element without namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
<div xmlns="http://www.com">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

When i get the child element using xpath and do `.ToString()`, it adds the parent namespace to it. How can i get the content without the redundant namespace in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this extension method. It will create another XElement recursively including its children w/o namespace. Extension method needs to be placed inside static class:

```
 public static XElement IgnoreNamespace(this XElement xelem)
    {
        XNamespace xmlns = "";
        var name = xmlns + xelem.Name.LocalName;
        return new XElement(name,
                        from e in xelem.Elements()
                        select e.IgnoreNamespace(),
                        xelem.Attributes()
                        );
    }


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var document = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><div xmlns=\"http://www.ya.com\"><div class=\"child\"></div></div>");
    var first = document.Root.Elements().First().IgnoreNamespace();
    Console.WriteLine(first.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Raman is nice but it will not work for XML like this:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.ya.com">
   <div class="child">
      **This is some text**
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my improved version that will work:

```
public static XElement IgnoreNamespace(this XElement xelem)
{
    XNamespace xmlns = "";
    var name = xmlns + xelem.Name.LocalName;

    var result = new XElement(name,
                     from e in xelem.Elements()
                     select e.IgnoreNamespace(),
                     xelem.Attributes()
                     );

    if (!xelem.HasElements)
        result.Value = xelem.Value;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: it's hard to tell if this solution works at all, given the input you provided, it throws `XmlException` : `The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://www.ya.com' within the same start element tag.`

Comment: turns out this solution doesn't work, because passing a `name` with no namespace, then copying the attributes (which would include the namespace declaration) is invalid as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers provided here worked for me. For anyone else that lands here, tested with my own large xaml file, and a sample included in the code snippet.

```
void Main()
{
    var path = @"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\sample.xml";
    var text = File.ReadAllText(path);
    var surrounded = "<test xmlns=\"http://www.ya.com\">" + text + "</test>";
    var xe = XElement.Parse(surrounded);

    xe.Dump();
    xe.StripNamespaces().Dump();

    var sampleText = "<test xmlns=\"http://www.ya.com\"><div class=\"child\" xmlns:diag=\"http://test.com\"> ** this is some text **</div></test>";
    xe = XElement.Parse(sampleText);
    xe.Dump();
    xe.StripNamespaces().Dump();
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static XNode StripNamespaces(this XNode n)
    {
        var xe = n as XElement;
        if(xe == null)
            return n;
        var contents = 
            // add in all attributes there were on the original
            xe.Attributes()
            // eliminate the default namespace declaration
            .Where(xa => xa.Name.LocalName != "xmlns")
            .Cast<object>()
            // add in all other element children (nodes and elements, not just elements)
            .Concat(xe.Nodes().Select(node => node.StripNamespaces()).Cast<object>()).ToArray();
        var result = new XElement(XNamespace.None + xe.Name.LocalName, contents);
        return result;

    }

#if !LINQPAD
    public static T Dump<T>(this T t, string description = null)
    {
        if(description != null)
            Console.WriteLine(description);
        Console.WriteLine(t);
        return t;
    }
#endif
}
```

written first in `F#` as:

```
let stripNamespaces (e:XElement):XElement=
    // if the node is not XElement, pass through
    let rec stripNamespaces (n:XNode): XNode =
        match n with
        | :? XElement as x -> 
            let contents = 
                x.Attributes() 
                // strips default namespace, but not other declared namespaces
                |> Seq.filter(fun xa -> xa.Name.LocalName <> "xmlns")
                |> Seq.cast<obj> 

                |> List.ofSeq 
                |> (@) (
                    x.Nodes() 
                    |> Seq.map stripNamespaces 
                    |> Seq.cast<obj> 
                    |> List.ofSeq
                )
            XElement(XNamespace.None + x.Name.LocalName, contents |> Array.ofList) :> XNode
        | x -> x
    stripNamespaces e :?> XElement
```